# why stack overflow removing the code and making it shorter?

Tags: discussion

[image]

why stack overflow removing the code and making it shorter ? after editing it happened.
it put some code in header, why is so ?
or am I missing something ?

Comment: You must start each code line with 4 spaces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, write the code with indentions. Then select the block of code you want and simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> OR Just type ``` twice and write something between them.

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Selected the code and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> **AND** you must use an extra enter key to separate the code and the simple text.

[image: Coding Style]